# Property 'location' does not exist on type 'File'

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I have changed multer to multer-s3. Changing in controllers for that. I will store "location" instead of "filename". But I am getting typescript error.

I am using Localstack for now.

Here is my code:

**multer.s3.middleware.ts**

```
import validateFileForBucket from '@/common/validateFileForBucket';
import { AWS_BUCKET_NAME } from '@/config';
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import multer from 'multer';
import multerS3 from 'multer-s3';

// Configure AWS for localstack
aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'testKEYId',
  secretAccessKey: 'testSecret',
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  sslEnabled: false,
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:4566',
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
} as any);

const s3 = new aws.S3();

// Define Multer-S3 upload
const uploadS3 = multer({
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const bucket = req.params.bucket;
    validateFileForBucket(bucket, file, cb);
  },
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3 as any,
    bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME as string,
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req: any, file, cb) {
      const bucket = req.params.bucket ? `${req.params.bucket}/` : '';
      cb(null, `${bucket}${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
  }),
});

export default uploadS3;
```

**user.route.ts**

```
this.router
  .route('/create')
  .post(
    authMiddleware,
    uploadS3.single('profileImage'),
    validationMiddleware(createUserSchema, 'body'),
    this.userController.create,
  );
```

**user.controller.ts**

```
public create = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  req.body.profileImage = req.file?.location;
  req.body.user = req.tokenData.user;
  const responseData = await this.userRepository.createUser(req.body as CreateUserInterface);
  return generalResponse(req, res, responseData, successMessage.USER_CREATE_SUCCESS, false, responseFlag.SUCCESS);
};
```

For some reason, I am getting typescript error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/user/user.controller.ts:24:39 - error TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'File'.

24     req.body.profileImage = req.file?.location;
```

I get file data if I log req.file, and it has location on it.

```
req.file:  {
  fieldname: 'profileImage',
  originalname: 'profile.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  size: 6182,
  bucket: 'aws-bucket-name',
  key: '1711716164482-profile.jpeg',
  acl: 'private',
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  contentDisposition: null,
  contentEncoding: null,
  storageClass: 'STANDARD',
  serverSideEncryption: null,
  metadata: { fieldName: 'profileImage' },
  location: 'http://localhost:4566/aws-bucket-name/1711716164482-profile.jpeg',
  etag: '"806170f0b2a191c8c967372af939cc6d"',
  versionId: undefined
}
```

Hovering over req.`file` shows

```
(property) Express.Request.file?: Express.Multer.File | undefined
Multer.File object populated by single() middleware.
```

Shouldn't it be `Express.MulterS3.File`?

being TS newbie, I have no idea how to fix this.
I have searched on google, stackoverflow and also on multer-s3 github issues. But no one seems to have got similar error.

I am not sure What I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.